# Python, wait on a file to zip before sending it

Tags: python

I want to send a zip file via FTP. I have a .cmd that works but my problem is  python fires the .cmd before the files are zipped so nothing gets sent. Here is my code.

```
Source = (r"D:\Backup\test2") #where the files originate
Destination = (r"D:\Backup\ZipFilesToMove") #where they move to
SendZipfiles = (['C:\BackupFiles\RichCopyControls.cmd']) #the .cmd file
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(Source) if isfile(join(Source,f)) ] v#get each file in folder
Amount = len(onlyfiles) #how many files are in folder
Counter = 0
lst = onlyfiles #give the list the name lst
while(Counter < Amount):
      zf = zipfile.ZipFile(lst[Counter],"w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,allowZip64=True) # create zip
      zf.write(os.path.join(lst[Counter])) #zip it up
      zf.close() #close the zip
      shutil.move(os.path.join(lst[Counter]),Destination) #move to zip folder
      p = subprocess.Popen(SendZipfiles) #the problem is here I think, this is where it runs the .cmd
```

The rest of the program works fine, the problem is the .cmd file is opened and done before the files have zipped so nothing is sent.
I have googled around and found subprocesses for .call and .wait. But,I dont understand how they function and cant find an example of them which I can mod and use. Thanks!

Comment: Just a style note. Title case is usually reserved for classes, not variables. That could be confusing to someone else reading your code.

Comment: I will remember that next time thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wait for all the files to be zipped and then move? I am not sure what your .cmd file does.

```
while Counter < Amount:
      zf = zipfile.ZipFile(lst[Counter],"w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,allowZip64=True) # create zip
      zf.write(os.path.join(lst[Counter])) #zip it up
      zf.close() #close the zip
      shutil.move(os.path.join(lst[Counter]),Destination) #move to zip folder
p = subprocess.Popen(SendZipfiles)
```

Comment: The problem is space I want to only hold the file for a limited time, zip it, send it, and delete it. the .cmd file is what does the FTP, it was written by someone else and must be used. otherwise I would have used python to send it.